# When a Button is pressed app crashes with a Firebase Related error

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift4.2, swift5

Before you read all of this, I'm sorry for the long post but I wanted to explain the situation as much as I could because I wasn't able to find a similar error online.

Hello guys, so I'm making this app in swift and it has a home screen with a "loginButton" and a "signUp"

I made all the app screens and its constraints on a regular file and after that being done I installed some pods.

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
```

After that I started configuring the Sign Up and the Log in View controllers to communicate with firebase.

The Sign Up was good but when I finished the Login, something happened.

Every time I clicked on the "loginButton" my app would crash for no apparent reason (to me, I'm not that experienced in swift and there are still a lot of errors I can't identify)

The error it gave me was "[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist"

But to me this doesn't seem to be the problem, since firebase is not giving me any error with the SignUp which is strange because both buttons have the same configuration.

I'm kinda desperate for help so if you guys need to see some code or anything please tell me and I will post it.

I already tried deleting the button segue that goes from the home screen to the login screen and the error is still going on.

Already deleted the LoginViewController that I have done to see if it really was any Firebase configuration that I had wrong, but the error still persists and I have no use of firebase on that view controller

and obviously already did the "To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist" that Xcode suggests in the error, and still it persisted. that time with a different error, the error was basically only telling me that I had disabled it and that the app couldn't run like that.

I can show you the Sign Up view controller code since it is identical to the Login one.

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SignInViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dismissButton: UIButton!


    var signupButton:UIButton!
    var activityView:UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Botão de Login Programatico porque o do desgin estava a dar demasiados problemas... tipo que este não vai dar, lol
        signupButton = RoundedWhiteButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 50))
        signupButton.setTitle("Log In", for: .normal)
        signupButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
        signupButton.setTitleColor(textColor, for: .normal)
        signupButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.frame.height - signupButton.frame.height - 24)
        //Evento HandleLogin
        signupButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSignup), for: .touchUpInside)
        signupButton.alpha = 0.5
        //Adicionar à view e chamar função "setLoginButton"
        view.addSubview(signupButton)
        setSignupButton(enabled: false)

        //Rodinha bonita que aparece no signupButton quando os dados estão a ser processados, só para não usar mais um CocoaPod
        activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
        activityView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
        activityView.center = signupButton.center

        view.addSubview(activityView)

        //já são meninos crescidos, já podem tomar conta de si mesmos.
        emailTextfield.delegate = self
        passwordTextField.delegate = self
        //estava a brincar. isto é para esta brincadeira funcionar como deve de ser xisdê
        emailTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)
        passwordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged), for: .editingChanged)


        //coias bonitas para as "notificações" do teclado
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        emailTextfield.becomeFirstResponder()
    }


    //Evento "touchUpInside" no dismissButton, faz com que a view volte para o ecrã principal

    @IBAction func handleDismissButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    //MARK: Funções

    //MARK: keyboardWillShow
    //recebe uma notificação quando o teclado "aparece", permitindo que o signupButton seja deslocado mais para cima, impedindo-o de ficar escondido atrás do teclado.
    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        let info = notification.userInfo!
        let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

        signupButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x,
                                     y: view.frame.height - keyboardFrame.height - 16.0 - signupButton.frame.height / 2)
        activityView.center = signupButton.center

    }

    //MARK: keyboardWillHide
    //recebe uma notificação quando o teclado "desaparece", permitindo que o signupButton seja deslocado para a sua posiçao inicial.
    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
        signupButton.center = CGPoint(x: view.center.x, y: view.frame.height - signupButton.frame.height)
        activityView.center = signupButton.center
    }

    //MARK: setLoginButton
    //Se o resultado for verdadeiro, o botão fica ativo e sem transparencia.
    func setSignupButton(enabled:Bool) {
        if enabled {
            signupButton.alpha = 1.0
            signupButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            signupButton.alpha = 0.5
            signupButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }

    //Nem sei muito bem, ainda estou para descobrir, mas isto de alguma maneira faz com que o botão "log in" fique ativo

    @objc func textFieldChanged(_ target:UITextField) {
        let email = emailTextfield.text
        let password = passwordTextField.text
        let formFilled = email != nil && email != "" && password != nil && password != ""
        setSignupButton(enabled: formFilled)
    }

    //evento que dá handle ao evento "touchUpInside" do "signupButton"
    @objc func handleSignup() {

        setSignupButton(enabled: false)
        signupButton.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        activityView.startAnimating()

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailTextfield.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!) { (user,error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error!)
            } else {
                print("Registration Successful!")            
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToMap", sender: self)
            }

        }




    }

}
```

If any of you guys can help me I would be very grateful, all I need the app to do right now is to work as expected, having a Login that redirects to the main app screen after the user entered its credentials.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @AfonsoCastelo, which line did you get crash?

Comment: avoid use force unwrap in your code. For example: in `func handleSignup()` use `guard let email = emailTextfield.text, let password = passwordTextField.text else { return }` same thing for print(error!), change your if to `ìf let err = error { print(err) }`. After that try to run your code again and if the crash still persist, take a print of the console and add to your question

Comment: Two things - the Firebase message *Analytics screen reporting is enabled* is not an error; it's just a message. Second thing is that if you're having an issue with your Login View Controller, you should include *that* code, not the Sign In View Controller code. If the code was identical, it would behave identically, which is isn't.

Comment: @EmreCiftci hey, it crashes on the "class AppDelegate:"

Comment: @Jay the code is the exact same on both View Controllers, but the Login one crashes as soon as I press the log in button on the app's home screen. even if the LoginViewController is empty it crashes.

Comment: Where do crash come from? You can find them by following the threads.

Comment: What is the 'crash'? Is there an error? Also, there's entirely too much code in the question. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)